# Fit the student’s t-distribution to the daily log-returns

Tags: r

I would appreciate help with how to fit the student’s *t-distribution* to the daily **log-returns** of a given stock (I used MSFT for a period that covers ten years).

I have calculated the daily log-returns, `microsoft.logr` plus produced its mean, `microsoft.logr.mean`, and standard deviation, `microsoft.logr.sd` which is approximately 0.000979 and 0.016269 respectively. The degrees of freedom will be chosen manually, for example one can use `df=7`.

This is what I tried:

```
df = 7

# histogram of Microsoft log-returns
hist(microsoft.logr, breaks = 50, freq = FALSE)

# density of student's t-test
x <- seq(min(microsoft.logr), max(microsoft.logr), by = 0.001) 
y <- (1/microsoft.logr.sd)*dt((x-microsoft.logr.mean)/microsoft.logr.sd,df)

# add fitted t-distribution 
lines(x,y,col="purple")
```

But since it is my first time fitting a distribution in R I wonder if this is correct? I got a little unsure since the t-distribution should have heavier tails than the normal distribution but I am not convinced that it is the case here. The plot for this is presented below.

[image]

Comment: This is really a statistics question so better on Cross-validated.  Also there might be useful information here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52688/method-of-moments-for-t-distribution

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Oh ok, my bad. Thank you for you information and for the link!